# Print Hex number as decimal

Tags: c, linux, terminal

I'm trying to make fdisk program in Linux. I have a buffer which contains the partition disk information(starting sector- ending sector- size of partition...etc).

The problem that I have buffer array `char buf[512]` and that buffer contains the needed info and I want to print it in decimal. The result should be `dec 2048` but my program print `hex 0800`

The program can see each digit eight zero zero and I want it to see eight hundreds.

---

### The Code

```
#define _LARGEFILE64_SOURCE
#define buff_SIZE 512

#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int main(int argc, char ** argv){


  int fd; // File descriptor
  unsigned char buf[buff_SIZE];

  if(argc<2) {
     perror("Error: No such file or directory");
     exit(2); // File scripted: 0 input 1 output 2 error
  }

  // Open Driver::
  if((fd=open(argv[1], O_RDONLY | O_LARGEFILE ))==-1){
     perror("Error: Can not open the file");
     exit(2);
  }

  // Reading file descriptor into buffer::
  if(read(fd, buf, buff_SIZE)!=buff_SIZE)
    perror("Error: Reading error");

  if ((buf[446]==0x80)||(buf[446]==0x00))
     printf("%x\n",buf[446]);
  int i;
  for(i=447;i<=449;i++)
    printf("%x\n",buf[i]);
  printf("Partation ID:%x\n",buf[450]);
  printf("Starting Sector:%x%x%x%x\n",buf[454],buf[455],buf[456],buf[457]); //***THE PROBLEM***

 close(fd);
 return 0;}
```

---

The output

```
80
20
21
0
Partation ID:83
Starting Sector:0800
```

This in hexa 800h i need it in decimal 2048

Comment: What does this have to do with `vi` ?

Comment: i wrote this code using vi{the text editor}.

Comment: **[Partation?](http://www.googlefight.com/index.php?lang=en_GB&word1=partation&word2=partition)** (also, I think you forgot to add the 'mouse', 'desk', 'man-hour' and 'food' tags)

Comment: I don't quite understand, you use `'%x'` to output, why not `%d`

Comment: when i use %d instead of %x i didn't get the desired decimal result but in case of using %x i get the hexa corresponding to desired number.
- My main problem to merge many array elements in one number to print it ex. need to merge x[1]=1 and x[2]=2 to print them in one element to print twelve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
printf("Starting Sector:%lu\n",
         (unsigned long)buf[454] * 0x1000
       + (unsigned long)buf[455] * 0x100
       + (unsigned long)buf[456] * 0x10
       + (unsigned long)buf[457] * 0x1);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This simple solution works however i wanted a simpler one but it's OK.